# Image scraping in access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have generated data matrix by using Access vba. Now I have to scrape that generated pic into my form each and everytime. Here is the code. Half part is generating barcode while half to scrape that picture in Access form is not working.

```
Private Sub Command24_Click()

Dim IE As New InternetExplorer

IE.Visible = True

IE.Navigate ("https://barcode.tec-it.com/en/DataMatrix?data=" & Forms!QRcodes!Text)
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until IE.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
StatusBar = "loading webpage...."

Dim img As Object
Dim html As HTMLDocument
Set html = IE.Document
Dim elementcol As Object, link As Object
Set elementcol = html.getElementsByTagName("img")

Dim doc As Object

Forms!QRcodes!OLEBound34 = elementcol

'Set img = ele.getElementsByTagName("img")
Set Tables!QRcodes!Matrix = elementcol

MsgBox "Getting Code"

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you give an example full url please and giver more detail on what not working means?

Comment: I wants to create datamatrix barcode in ms access. The solution I found is that I ahould create onlime and then paaste it in access form. Now I am able to generate lknk online by using vba but unablee to paste that picture in my forms. I need changing variable each time user enter a new text. Code is not copying that image.

Comment: I think have to save image as an external file then load the file into OLEObject field or control. I don't use OLE, I save image filepath to text field then use Image control ControlSource set to that field. Saving images into db just uses up Access 2GB size limit. Images can be pasted to Excel sheet but AFAIK, not to Access field or control.

Comment: Well, maybe can paste from clipboard. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.access.formscoding/4EXv2d1f0mY

Answer (score 0):

Grab the skeleton for the full URL to only the *generated picture* (as displayed on the site) - for example:

```
https://barcode.tec-it.com/barcode.ashx?data=12345678&code=DataMatrix&multiplebarcodes=false&translate-esc=false&unit=Fit&dpi=96&imagetype=Gif&rotation=0&color=%23000000&bgcolor=%23ffffff&qunit=Mm&quiet=0&dmsize=Default' alt='Barcode Generator TEC-IT
```

Then you can use my code and demo published in one of my articles:

[Show pictures directly from URLs in Access forms and reports](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/29679/Show-pictures-directly-from-URLs-in-Access-forms-and-reports.html)

The two main functions downloads pictures directly, one is caching the download:

```
' Download a file or a page with public access from the web as a cached file of Internet Explorer.
' Returns the full path of the cached file if success, an empty string if not.
'
' Examples:
'
' Download a file:
'   Url = "https://www.codeproject.com/script/Membership/ProfileImages/%7Ba82bcf77-ba9f-4ec3-bbb3-1d9ce15cae23%7D.jpg"
'   Result = DownloadCacheFile(Url)
'   Result -> C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\IE\B2IHEJQZ\{a82bcf77-ba9f-4ec3-bbb3-1d9ce15cae23}[2].png
'
' Download a page:
'   Url = "https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1022704/Rounding-Values-Up-Down-By-Or-To-Significant-Figur?display=Print"
'   Result = DownloadCacheFile(Url)
'   Result -> C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\IE\B2IHEJQZ\Rounding-Values-Up-Down-By-Or-To-Significant-Figur[1].htm
'
' 2017-05-25. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function DownloadCacheFile( _
    ByVal Url As String) _
    As String

    Const BufferLength  As Long = 1024
    Const BindFDefault  As Long = 0
    Const ErrorNone     As Long = 0

    Dim FileName        As String
    Dim LocalFileName   As String
    Dim Result          As Long

    ' Create buffer for name of downloaded and/or cached file.
    FileName = Space(BufferLength - 1) & vbNullChar
    ' Download file or page.
    ' Return name of cached file in parameter FileName.
    Result = URLDownloadToCacheFile(0, Url & vbNullChar, FileName, BufferLength, BindFDefault, 0)

    ' Trim file name.
    LocalFileName = Split(FileName, vbNullChar)(0)

    DownloadCacheFile = LocalFileName

End Function
```

I tested with a few URLs, and the codes were displayed at once:

[image]

Comment: I want too just display image in form directly from web don't want to save it

Comment: You won't. It's a temp file you don't have to worry about, and it operates exactly the same way the browser does behind the scene. Further, it is much faster than loading and operating a browser object.